# How to avoid PHP nested if...else... conditions and write clean, easy to understand code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, coding-style

I am writing a login method in codeigniter where user will enter email and password and then it will do following things:

1. Validate user input -> If valid do point#2
2. Get user details from database -> If success query do point#3
3. Verify the password -> If verified login to the system

I know I can achieve the above by using pure nested if...else condition but then it will be very tedious and hard to read.
So, I tried it in this way -

```
// Empty array to hold processing errors
$processing_errors = array();

// Check for valid input
if(!$is_valid_input) array_push($processing_errors, "Invalid inputs");

// Get user details
if($get_user_details)
{   
    // Verify the user
    if(!$is_correct_user) array_push($processing_errors, "Incorrect username or password.");
}
else array_push($processing_errors, "Database query error");

// Check if processing errors is empty 
if(empty($processing_errors)) echo "Successfully logged in."; // Success
else foreach($processing_errors as $errors) echo $errors; // Errors
```

But the problem with above approach is it will still execute the code after `Check for valid input` even if it returns false and will take unnecessary processing time.

What is the best approach to write neat and clean readable code?

Comment: Is this inside a class in Codeigniter?

Comment: @vivek_23 Yes, it's a method inside a class.

Comment: You can break down into more methods to make it look cleaner. This wouldn't make the code concise but will be more readable.

Comment: @vivek_23 Is it really a bad practice to declare an empty array to hold processing errors of further code blocks...Does it really impact the performance?

Comment: It doesn't impact performance and that is the only way to hold multiple errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can break these into methods exposing only the login request method and keeping everything else internal(as in `private` methods) as shown below. `userLogin` is where the request comes in.

**Snippet:**

```
class LoginController extends CI_Controller{
    private $errors;

    function __construct(){
        $this->errors = []; // initialize error bag to an empty array
        /*
          load needed models
        */
    }

    private function validateInput($post_data){
        /*
          validate user details
        */

        if(!$is_valid_input){
            $this->errors[] = '';
        }

        return $is_valid_input;
    }

    private function getUserDetails($post_data){
        /*
            get the user data using models
        */
        return $user_data;
    }

    private function verifyUser($post_data){
        $user_data = $this->getUserDetails($post_data);
        $is_correct_user = $user->email == $post_data['email'] && password_verify($post_data['password'],$user->password);

        if(!$is_correct_user){
            $this->errors[] = 'Incorrect username or password.';
        }

        return $is_correct_user;
    }

    private function displayErrors(){
        foreach($this->errors as $current_error){
            echo $current_error,"<br/>";
        }
    }

    public function userLogin(){
        $data = $this->input->post();
        try{
            if($this->validateInput($data) && $this->verifyUser($data)){
                echo "Successfully logged in";
                /* Your futher code */
            }else{
                $this->displayErrors();
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage(); // if you throw some Exception in your model for some situations. Better to have exact class name of Exception for faster lookup of the class
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try but I think this would be the longest approach....

Comment: @MuhammadTarique Yes, as I said earlier, this wouldn't make the code concise, but would make it more readable. Also, it's always good to go with an OOP based approach than a procedural one in an OOP based framework.